# how to add data to array or sub collection in Firestore flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add to an array in my Firestore doc or even tried to add a sub collection to get all users who've joined a certain group, but anytime I do so it either creates a new doc or it doesn't update it. Any help will be appreciated.

The function is below

Future joinGroup(String groupId,  String Username, UserUid) async {
String retVal = 'error';

```
try {
  members.add(Username);
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('groups')
  .doc(groupId)
  .collection('members')
  .add({
    'name': Username,
    'id': UserUid
  });
  
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('groups')
  .doc(groupId)
  .collection('members')
  .add({
    'members': FieldValue.arrayUnion(members)
  });
  retVal = 'success';
        
  print(groupId);
  print(members);
} catch (e) {}
return retVal;
     
  }
```

Comment: follow this documentaion. it might help you - https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#updating-documents

Answer (score 0):

Any time you call `add`, Firestore creates a new document. If you want to update an existing document, you'll need to know its document ID and then can do:

```
var docRef = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('groups')
  .doc(groupId)
  .collection('members')
  .add({
    'name': Username,
    'id': UserUid
  });

await docRef.update({ 'name': 'new username' });
```